# JQuery Open new screen

Tags: jquery

I am trying to open a new screen with JQuery, but have to pass variables to the new screen. Is this possible? I have a C# application in Visual Studio 2012 with MVC 4.
My code looks like this:

```
    $('#AddCopyRuleButton').click(function () {
        var url = '@Url.Action("GetDetails")';
        var data = {
            systemCode: $('#SystemCode').val(),
            productCode: $('#Products').val(),
            subProductCode: $('#SubProducts').val(),
            division: $('#Division').val(),
            dcarFrom: $('#DCARFrom').val(),
            dcarTo: $('#DCARTo').val(),
            accountNumber: $('#AccountNumber').val(),
            counterPartyCode: $('#CounterParty').val()
        };

        $.getJSON(url, data, function (data) {
        });
    });
```

Inside the JSON code, I want to redirect to another page, and send the data along with the request to the new page. The current page should be closed.

Also, how do I use the data passed to the new screen?

Comment: Are you talking about doing a POST to a different page? or a GET with JSON as a query parameter? either way, MVC auto-mapping is probably your friend, you should be able to specify an appropriately named parameter on the controller action that is handling your request and that will map for you.

Comment: Also, is there some reason you want to open a new page/screen, rather than navigate in the usual fashion?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an async request for that, use a raw urlencoded `GET` request.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along the lines of

```
// Parent window
$('#AddCopyRuleButton').click(function () {
    var p=window.open("Popup.html");

    // wait for the child to get populated and then close this window
    window.close();
});

function getData() {
    var iHoldData;
    // Put some stuff in iHoldData
    return iHoldData;
}
```

And for the child

```
// Child window
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
        var iRecieveData = window.opener.getData();
    }
});
```